# Excel Graph Issue in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want Vertical Axis like this
[image]

But I'm getting this
[image]

I'm using EPPlus 3.1 (http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

```html
using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var workbook = package.Workbook;
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

            worksheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Widgets";
            worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = 20;
            worksheet.Cells["C3"].Value = 5;
            worksheet.Cells["C4"].Value = 30;
            worksheet.Cells["C5"].Value = 32;
            worksheet.Cells["C6"].Value = 17;

            worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "Widgets2";
            worksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = 1;
            worksheet.Cells["D3"].Value = 2;
            worksheet.Cells["D4"].Value = 3;
            worksheet.Cells["D5"].Value = 4;
            worksheet.Cells["D6"].Value = 5;

            worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Jan";
            worksheet.Cells["B3"].Value = "Feb";
            worksheet.Cells["B4"].Value = "Mar";
            worksheet.Cells["B5"].Value = "Apr";
            worksheet.Cells["B6"].Value = "May";

            var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart", eChartType.ColumnClustered);

            var series = chart.Series.Add("C2:C6", "B2:B6"); 
            series.HeaderAddress = new ExcelAddress("'Sheet1'!C1");

            series = chart.Series.Add("D2:D6", "B2:B6");
            series.HeaderAddress = new ExcelAddress("'Sheet1'!D1");

            package.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("Upload/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx")));

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn off the minor tick marks on the value axis. In Excel VBA it's this, I'll let you convert it:

```
chart.Axes(xlValue).MinorTickMark = xlTickMarkNone
```

Comment: Correct answer : chart.YAxis.MinorTickMark = eAxisTickMark.None;